# Mongo ChangeStream with Spring producing error: state should be: open error after UI eventsource closure

Tags: spring, mongodb, changestream

I am trying to troubleshoot a mongodb changestream error.
I am watching for changes on a collection with...

```
public Flux<Clone> watchForCloneCollectionChanges() {

            // set changestream options to watch for any changes to the clone collection
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.orOperator(where("operationType").is("insert"), where("operationType").is("replace"));
            ChangeStreamOptions options = ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
                    .filter(Aggregation.newAggregation(Clone.class,
                            Aggregation.match(criteria)
                    )).returnFullDocumentOnUpdate().build();

            // return a flux that watches the changestream and returns the full document
            return reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream("clone", options, Clone.class)
                    .map(ChangeStreamEvent::getBody)
                    .doOnError(throwable -> logger.error("Error with the teams changestream event: " + throwable.getMessage(), throwable));
    }
```

using the handler

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> watchClones(ServerRequest request) {
        Flux<ServerSentEvent<Clone>> sse = this.cloneWatcher.watchForCloneCollectionChanges()
                .map(clone -> ServerSentEvent.<Clone>builder()
                        .data(clone)
                        .build());
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromServerSentEvents(sse));
```

and the router function

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(CloneHandler cloneHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(RequestPredicates.GET("/clones"), cloneHandler::getClones)
                .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/clones/watch"), cloneHandler::watchClones);

    }
```

For my front end I am using Angular using behavior subjects and Eventsource to connect. The problem I am having is after I close the page it seems like the changeStream is still watching for changes even though the front end has closed the event source.  As a result when a document is updated spring throws the follow error:

> 2020-01-06 15:22:34.312 ERROR 27772 --- [andler-executor] org.mongodb.driver.operation             : Callback onResult call produced an error
>
> com.mongodb.MongoException: state should be: open
>       at com.mongodb.MongoException.fromThrowableNonNull(MongoException.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.onError(AbstractSubscription.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription$2.onResult(MongoIterableSubscription.java:93) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription$2.onResult(MongoIterableSubscription.java:85) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$3.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$3.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:129) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$4.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:168) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor$4.onResult(AsyncChangeStreamBatchCursor.java:159) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:331) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:310) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:242) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:83) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:467) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:111) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:401) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:376) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:677) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:644) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:514) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:511) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:220) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:203) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannel$3$1.run(AsynchronousTlsChannel.java:151) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
>       at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.session.BaseClientSessionImpl.advanceOperationTime(BaseClientSessionImpl.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.session.ClientSessionContext.advanceOperationTime(ClientSessionContext.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ClusterClockAdvancingSessionContext.advanceOperationTime(ClusterClockAdvancingSessionContext.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.updateSessionContext(InternalStreamConnection.java:537) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at >>com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$800(InternalStreamConnection.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       at >>com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:385) [mongodb-driver-core-3.11.1.jar:na]
>       ... 14 common frames omitted

I've searched high and low but cant find a solution.  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug solved in 3.12.1.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3487